# vba sql statement error "missing operator"

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I can't get it work in VBA althought it works within access.
Which is the mistake?

```
Private Sub Command517_Click()
Dim SQL As String

    SQL = "SELECT Tags.Tag, MacroAttività.[Nome/Descrizione], MacroAttività.ID," & _
    " MacroAttività.Descrizione, MacroAttività.[Data inizio attività], " & _
    " MacroAttività.[Data fine prevista], MacroAttività.[Data fine effettiva], " & _
    " MacroAttività.Note,operatore.Nome, Tipologia.Tipologia " & _
    " FROM Tipologia INNER JOIN (operatore INNER JOIN (MacroAttività INNER JOIN Tags ON MacroAttività.ID = Tags.[ID macro attività]) " & _
    " ON operatore.ID = MacroAttività.Leader) ON Tipologia.ID = MacroAttività.Tipologia WHERE " & _
    "(((Tags.Tag) = [Forms]![MacroAttività]![Text511]) " & _
    " UNION ALL SELECT Tags.Tag, MacroAttività.[Nome/Descrizione], " & _
    " MacroAttività.Descrizione, MacroAttività.ID, " & _
    " MacroAttività.Leader, MacroAttività.[Data inizio attività], " & _
    " MacroAttività.[Data fine prevista], MacroAttività.[Data fine effettiva], " & _
    " MacroAttività.Note, MacroAttività.Tipologia " & _
    " FROM MacroAttività INNER JOIN Tags ON MacroAttività.ID = Tags.[ID macro attività] " & _
    " WHERE (((Tags.Tag)=[Forms]![MacroAttività]![Text513])); "
DoCmd.RunSQL SQL
End Sub
```

Comment: What about creating a procedure with a parameter e.g. `CREATE PROCEDURE GetStuff ( :tag VARCHAR(20) ) AS SELECT * FROM Stuff WHERE tag = :tag;` ...then in VBA code simply invoke the proc and pass a value for the parameter value?

Answer (score 2):

Form variables have to be read from outside of the SQL statement, so my solution closes the SQL statement adds the form variable and then reopens the SQL quotation. I have added string qualifiers(single quotes) around the form variables; assuming they are strings by the use of "text".

```
varSQL = "SELECT Tags.Tag, MacroAttività.[Nome/Descrizione], MacroAttività.ID," & _
" MacroAttività.Descrizione, MacroAttività.[Data inizio attività], " & _
" MacroAttività.[Data fine prevista], MacroAttività.[Data fine effettiva], " & _
" MacroAttività.Note,operatore.Nome, Tipologia.Tipologia " & _
" FROM Tipologia INNER JOIN (operatore INNER JOIN (MacroAttività INNER JOIN Tags ON MacroAttività.ID = Tags.[ID macro attività]) " & _
" ON operatore.ID = MacroAttività.Leader) ON Tipologia.ID = MacroAttività.Tipologia WHERE " & _
"(((Tags.Tag) ='" & [Forms]![MacroAttività]![Text511] & "')" & _
" UNION ALL SELECT Tags.Tag, MacroAttività.[Nome/Descrizione], " & _
" MacroAttività.Descrizione, MacroAttività.ID, " & _
" MacroAttività.Leader, MacroAttività.[Data inizio attività], " & _
" MacroAttività.[Data fine prevista], MacroAttività.[Data fine effettiva], " & _
" MacroAttività.Note, MacroAttività.Tipologia " & _
" FROM MacroAttività INNER JOIN Tags ON MacroAttività.ID = Tags.[ID macro attività] " & _
" WHERE (((Tags.Tag)='" & [Forms]![MacroAttività]![Text513] & "')); "
```

`SQL` is a reserved word so change your SQL variable name to something like `varSQL`. (Update: not a reserved word)

`currentdb.execute` and `domcd.runSQL` only work for action queries as far as I am aware. you cant execute a select query using these methods. try the following:

```
dim rs as recordset
dim varSQL as string

varSQL = "SELECT..."

set rs=currentdb.openrecordset(varSQL,dbOpenDynaset)

me.[text1] = rs.fieldname
'send recordset values to form

rs.close
```

Comment: It gave me bracket error in the first form variable, I added a bracket here & [Forms]![MacroAttività]![Text511]) & "')" & _ then it gave the same error missing operator.

Comment: My edit should work, I moved the close bracket back in to the SQL statement.

Comment: no it's definitely not an action query. It just receives the criteria from a textbox and gives me back the results on a form.
How should I open a recordset?

Comment: anything at all? Please Help

Comment: I know select isnt an action query. what I meant was you cant use `currentcb.execute` or `docmd.runsql` and have "SELECT" in your statement. i'll edit my post.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm making a project for the lab where I work and access and VBA are relatively a new world so I have many things to learn. I think SO would be a better place if there were more people like you and less people who dislike question that are of an inferior level compared to their own. Every walk begins with a step..

Comment: @LiamH: SQL is not a reserved word in VBA. You can freely name a variable that.

Comment: LiamH what does  me.[text1] = rs.fieldname do specifically?

Comment: It was just an example. The fields you have now selected in your query can be used using the `rs.` and you can put them in to your form